# How can I even out colors so text is readable against them at any given hue and lightness?

Tags: colors, hsl, ui-design

Anyone who frequently does UI likely knows that for a given color `hsl(H, 100%, 50%)` (syntax is CSS) not all values of H will produce a color suitable to be placed under arbitrarily black or white text. The specific fact I'm noting is that certain colors (green) appear especially bright and other (blue) appear especially dark.

Well suppose I would like a user to be able to enter a color hue and have the color always appear with a consistent brightness so that one of either white or black text is guaranteed to always be readable on top of it. I would like all colors to also maintain the most vivid level of saturation they can given the constraint on brightness.

Here is a quick example of what I've tried so far. I start with a grid of squared like this rendered using a bunch of html `div` elements. Essentially these are hue values roughly from 0 to 360 along the horizontal axis and lightness values from roughly 0% to 100% along the vertical axis. All saturation value are set to 100%.

[image]

Using a JS library library called [chroma.js](https://vis4.net/chromajs/), I now process all colors using the `color.luminance` function, whose definition seems to be to do what I'm looking for. I just passed the lightness of the hsl value in as the parameter to the function. I don't know for sure that this is the best way to accomplish my goal though since I'm not familiar with all the terminology at play here. Please note that my choice to use this library is by no means a constraint on how I want to go about this. It just represents my attempt at solving the problem.

[image]

The colors certainly now have a more consistent lightness, but the spectrum now seems particularly vivid around the orange to cyan area and particularly dull everywhere else. Also the colors seems to drop very quickly away from black at the top.

Hopefully this example helps a bit to express what I'm trying to accomplish here. Does any know what they best way to go about this is?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to generate the two images?  Is your goal to find a color for a given hue (and with maximum "S" in HSL) such that the color is neither "too light" nor "too dark" and yet is readable on white text or black text or both?  This involves two scores: closeness of the color's "L" (in HSL) to 0.5, and the color's [contrast ratio](https://peteroupc.github.io/colorgen.html#Contrast_Ratio) with white or with black, whichever is higher.  Then the solution may be to find the "L" that maximizes these two scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Check out [HSLuv](http://www.hsluv.org/). It balances out all the hues in the spectrum so that at any given saturation and lightness, all hues will have the exact same perceived brightness to the human eye.

This solved my problem because now I can just set my text color to white (for example) and then as long as the text is readable against a certain HSLuv lightness it is guaranteed that it will be readable against any hue and saturation used in combination with that lightness. Magic.